# Download file from server with Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a new file Excel, and with the next code, I can write and open the file, but I want to download the file to the user's computer, without open it. I was reading about servlet download, but that examples have a URL, and I dont know what URL to write there.

```
public void ExportarTotalClientes()
    {
        if(listaClientesExportar.size()>0)
        {               
            String rutaArchivo = System.getProperty("user.home")+"/ReporteCasos.xls";
            File archivoXLS = new File(rutaArchivo);
            if(archivoXLS.exists()) archivoXLS.delete();        
            try {
                archivoXLS.createNewFile();
                Workbook libro = new HSSFWorkbook();
                FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream(archivoXLS);
                Sheet hoja = libro.createSheet("Mi hoja de trabajo 1");
                for(int f=0;f<=listaClientesExportar.size();f++){               
                    if(f == 35000)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    Row fila = hoja.createRow(f);   
                    Cell celda0 = fila.createCell(0);
                    Cell celda1 = fila.createCell(1);
                    if(f==0)
                    {
                        celda0.setCellValue("RUT");
                        celda1.setCellValue("COMUNA");
                    }
                    else
                    {                       
                        celda0.setCellValue(listaClientesExportar.get(f-1).getRut());
                        celda1.setCellValue(listaClientesExportar.get(f-1).getComuna());

                    }

                }
                libro.write(archivo);
                archivo.close();
                DesktopApi.open(archivoXLS);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't do this without a URL

Comment: DOWNload or UPload ?

Comment: @JacekCz Download

Comment: Sorry, this is code producing document, giver. And giver cannot download :)